# Vim equivalent of `preg_quote()` and `quotemeta`

Tags: regex, vim

In vimscript I can regexp-match stuff with `matchstr()` and `matchlist()`

But what if I have to append to the pattern a ***user-provided string***?
How can I quote meta characters in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything that does that, but you could use a magicness modifier which might be good enough. Let's say you have the following expression:

```
let pattern = '\<'.word.'\>'
```

if `word` is a user-supplied string, then (if I understand correctly) you'd like to ignore all special modifiers in it. To do that, use "very nomagic mode". By putting a "\V" in front of the pattern, you make the pattern behave almost like a literal string. Afterwards, put "\m" to restore normal behaviour. In this case:

```
let pattern = '\<\V'.word.'\m\>'
```

Note, however, that this is not *exactly* what you're asking for. If the user enters `foo(*bar)`, it will work just fine, but if it's `foo(\*bar)`, it won't, because the `\*` pair is being interpreted as a star modifier. If you don't know about these modes, try `:help /\V` to get a better idea of how magicness works.

Comment: Mh, yes, reminds me of `\Q` and `\E` from PCRE.  
It certainly isn't perfect as it is... (in my understanding does nothing against the user inserting a `\m` into the search string) But then maybe, it can be alleviated with a further `let s:pattern=substitute(s:pattern,'\\m','\\\\m')`, approved.

Comment: Actually: `let s:pattern=substitute(s:pattern,'\\','\\\\','g')`